# Run npm install for two different package.json in parallel

Tags: node.js, npm-install, npm-scripts

I want to run npm install for two different package.json in parallel or one after the other.

I have two `package.json` in two different folders under the same project. One is for the front end and one is for the back end.

My project structure looks as follows:

```
package.json
/backend
 -- package.json
```

I want to hack into the `package.json` located in my root something like this:

```
"dep": "npm i \"npm install --prefix backend\"",
```

So when I run: `npm run dep`. npm install runs for my `package.json` in the root and the one in the **backend** folder.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is this:

```
 "deps": "npm i && npm --prefix ./backend install",
```